# Query to only show user data from their group based on login table

Tags: sql, oracle

We currently have apps for each office that only shows those that log in data from their office, right now that means having a separate app for each office, which means if we make application changes I have to update 20 different apps.

The logins are done through APEX with a custom authentication scheme that only allows a person to login if the office designation matches the app.

What I would like to figure out is how I can write the sql query that when a person logs in they only see the data from their office so I can get down to one application instead of having an app for each office.

Here's the structure of the table that contains the logins.

```
    "PKEY" NUMBER, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "OFFICE" VARCHAR2(50), 
     CONSTRAINT "LOGINS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PKEY")
```

And here's code from one of the current queries that's used to bring up office submittal information.

```
    select "PKEY", 
"DATE_SUB",
"CLIENT",
"CANDIDATE",
"RECRUITER",
"CONTACT",
"SALES",
dbms_lob.getlength("RESUME") "RESUME",
"MIMETYPE",
"FILENAME",
"POSITION",
"AVAILABILITY",
"RATE",
"ISSUES",
"WHEN_INT",
"FEEDBACK",
"REQ_PRIORITY",
"OFFICE",
"NOTES",
"REJECT",
"INT_FB"
from "SUBS"
WHERE "OFFICE" = 'OFFICE1'
AND ("REJECT" = 'Accepted' or "REJECT" IS NULL)
AND SALES != 'House'
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can use the "OFFICE" field in the logins table and compare that against the "OFFICE" field in the "SUBS" table so that APEX only shows results to a user that contains the same "OFFICE" designation that's in the logins table.

Example: User Joe Smith logs in as jsmith and he's in OFFICE1, so when he logs in he'll only see data that contains OFFICE1 in the OFFICE field in the table. User Jane Brown logs in to the same app as jbrown and she's in OFFICE2 so she only sees the data that has OFFICE2 in the OFFICE field.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: Can you join the logins table and subs table using some common column?

Comment: I kinda hoping to avoid a join, all I really want to happen is for the query to compare the OFFICE designation in the LOGINS table to the OFFICE designation in the SUBS table and only show rows where the user's OFFICE in the logins table is the same as the SUBS table.

Comment: @greg - How do you expect to compare without a join? You need that value somewhere at runtime to use as the filter. One other option would be an on login trigger that stores the value in a package variable that the query then uses, but that is unlikely to be any more efficient than a join.. You alternative is to look into something like Oracle Row Level Security (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28529/intro.htm or http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/oracle-row-level-security-part-1) but then you need to find a way to integrate that with your custom APEX login mechanism

Comment: @MichaelBroughton I do apologize, I'm not great with sql, I'm just "Ok", so if a join is the best way then I'll go that route.

I just want a simple method of being able to accomplish this, so any ideas anyone has I'd gladly use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select * from login where office = (
    select office from subs where login.office = subs.office
);
```

This will return all login rows where the office data is matching. I may have misunderstood your initial question, you may require the reverse query:

```
select * from subs where office = (
    select office from login where subs.office = login.office
);
```

Syntax is character insensitive, hence my lack of formatting, you may wish to capatalise various parts of the query. Good Luck!

Comment: That's almost perfect, but I need to make sure that the rows that are displayed match both the logins office and subs office based on username.

So that a user who logs in from OFFICE1 only sees OFFICE1's rows and a user from OFFICE2 only sees OFFICE2's.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but in case anyone else needs to learn how to do this.

Just create a hidden field on the page and create a computation for that field using a PL/SQL function body like this.

```
  DECLARE 
  v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
  SELECT NAME
  INTO v_value
  FROM LOGINS
  WHERE USERNAME = :APP_USER;
  RETURN v_value;
  END;
```

Use what ever reference you need to from your table to (in this case, recruiter name) and just a AND or WHERE clause to your query referencing that hidden field.